# Assigning JavaScript to a certain body class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to run this script on a specific page but also, only for a specific body class. example: On this page it has `<body class="category-type-plp">`

How do I assign my script to "category-type-plp" ??

```js
plpSpaceRemove: function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
          if ($('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').length % 4 === 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < ($('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').length / 4); i++) {
              let remove = true;
              $('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').slice(i * 4, 4 * (i + 1)).each(function() {
                  if ($(this).find(".bv-stars-wrap 
                      ").length != 0) {
                      remove = false;
                    }
                  });
                if (remove) {
                  $('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').slice(i * 4, 4 * (i + 1)).each(function() {
                      if ($(this).find(".bv-stars-wrap 
                          ").length === 0) {
                          $(this).css("display", "none");
                        }
                      });
                  }
                }
              }
              else {
                for (let i = 0; i < ($('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').length / 3); i++) {
                  let remove = true;
                  $('.bv-tile.bv-inline-rating-outer').slice(i * 3, 3 * (i + 1)).each(function() {
                        if ($(this).find('.bv-stars-wrap 
                            ').length != 0) {
                            remove = false;
                          }
                        });
```

Comment: Put the code in a function, and run that function only if `body` has class `category-type-plp`..?

Comment: `plpSpaceRemove: function() {` why is that wrapping the document.ready?

Comment: You have some weird separators chars in the code `(HTML &#8233; · PSEP)`: 
` `

Comment: Its added to a larger .js file with other scripts running. So I had to add above  $(function () {  _self.plpSpaceRemove(); });

Comment: Why? Why would you need to do so? What does plpSpaceRemove do?

Comment: well there are other scripts on the file it has 

_self.universalCarousel();
 _self.swatchOrderFix();
 _self.pdpYouTubeFix();
  _self.swatchVariationsFix();
 });
So i thought I had to add my code with a function there

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your body has a certain class:

```js
if (!$('body').hasClass('some-class')) return;
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Where would i best place this code to mine?